# Конфиг файл вебпака выдаёт ошибку

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

webpack 4. Вот мой файл webpack.config.js

```js
let path = require('path');

let conf = {
    entry: './qwe/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    }
};

module.export = conf;
```

Когда запускаю в консоли"--mode production", Выдаётся ошибка:
**ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\Aquarius\WebstormProjects\webpack'**

Почему? Я не хочу переименовывать папку qwe в src

Comment: `Entry` не забыли?

Answer (score 0):

Я написал module.export вместо module.exports, из-за чего 2 дня промучился...

Answer (score -2):

Думаю потому что в вебпак 4 уже встроенна некая структура расположения файлов(как например  у express есть свой шаблон построения приложения), которой вы должны придерживаться в своём проекте. Поэтому из 4 версии выпили лишние конфиги и теперь позиционируют себя как система сборки, для которой по сути не нужно ничего настраивать или делать  это по минимуму..